# How to restrict the editing area in the ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor to edit my html text, here i want to restrict editable area in the ckeditor, i know how to give width and height for the ckeditor but i do not know how to give width and height for the ckeditor editing area.

Suppose if i give 700px width then user should enter the text only upto 700px, after that it should come to the next line.

I gave like below

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'divedit', {
    toolbar: 'Basic',
    uiColor: '#9AB8F3',
    width: '700px',
    height:'200px'
});
```

but it is showing scroll bar if the user types text beyond 700px.

Comment: I feel that what you want to do is pretty crazy and perhaps some details would make it possible to create a right solution. But anyway, you can retrieve the "editing area" (which is called *editable*) with `CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.editable()` (`CKEDITOR.replace` also returns `CKEDITOR.editor` object). Then you can apply any style you want with [`CKEDITOR.dom.element.setStyle`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-setStyle). In your case it will be `height:?` and `overflow-y:hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a strange requirement. I would try this:

1. Before saving get the editor contents
2. Insert into a preview div that has the exact same CSS as your requirements / target **but no width**
3. Get the width of the content with javascript
4. Check if width > 700, alert message the user that their content Sucks and don't save
5. Otherwise, save

Don't do this with every change event - it will murder your performance at some point.

BTW, I never use static width content in CKE, so I cannot see how this is ever a problem, but I guess you have different requirements or something. If this is to stop users from entering `OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO...` or such content that overflow from the box you are outputting content with, don't worry about it. Content such as that should be deleted or edited using other means and you can also use [CSS to control overflows](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_overflow-xy). Or you can validate word widths with a max chars per word limitation or something.